# Is it possible to mix italic and normal font in a label?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have concatenate the values of two field like

"BYKV_BTYP"  || '/' ||  "FFH"

Is it possible to draw the value of the column  "FFH" in italic if it is not empty and the value of "BYKV_BTYP"  normal? Such as

G212-*6510*

Comment: There is an old/existing [feature request](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4080) for this but I don't think it has been implemented (certainly not in 2.6).  It certainly would be nice to have.

Comment: @MappaGnosis please post that as an answer.

Comment: @underdark NP posted as requested

Answer (score 3):

*(Comment reposted as an answer as per Underdark's request)*

There is an old/existing [feature reques](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/14063)t for this but I don't think it has been implemented (certainly not in 2.6). It certainly would be nice to have

Answer (score 1):

It can be done if you "Render as HTML" the label.

So the expression would be:

```
[% "BYKV_BTYP" %]/<i>[% "FFH" %]</i>
```

[image]

This would also work for Bold, and other text styles.

Comment: Please note that as of QGIS 3.10 this works only if four conditions are met: (1) the text is inside a label object in layout view, not a label in the project/map view; (2) the layout is generated as an atlas; (3) all the fields belong to the coverage layer defined in the Atlas tab; (4) atlas preview is enabled. It is not possible yet to enable html rendering for labels in a map (e.g. mountains peaks). If you are looking for this kind of customisation please look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48389/how-to-create-a-label-combining-different-font-sizes-or-types for some workarounds.

Comment: You are correct. I think I misunderstood what label the poster was referring to. This is for print composer labels, not map feature labels.

Comment: I think the original question was somehow unclear. Your answer addresses the case mentioned in the feature request in QGIS issue tracker and improves at the same time @mappagnosis answer, so... thank you!