# Custom layer styling in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, layers

In QGIS, Can we render a layer's label as HTML to be able to style label partially? 
For example, a feature's label including two attribute, an attribute will render bold while the other one will render italic.

Maybe something like;
bold("an_attr") || italic("another_attr")

Comment: Most likely not. A few days ago I read a question about "different colours in label" and the answer was "not yet".

Comment: A good solution to your problem was proposed few days ago in this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357234/is-there-any-way-to-style-a-substring-of-a-label-with-a-different-style-without/357244#comment584543_357244

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently as of at least QGIS 3.12.

There is a feature request for this:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/14063

And the same question:

[Is it possible to mix italic and normal font in a label?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140147/is-it-possible-to-mix-italic-and-normal-font-in-a-label/344682#344682)