# Single text label in dual font size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, font

I can create a point label with single size font (example)

[image]

However, I need to emphasize Japanese characters, make them larger in comparison to latin characters (example)

[image]

I tried some CASE WHEN expressions for Label -> Size option, but with no success.

Any hints (for QGIS version 2.18, alternatively v 3.x)?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want using Rule-Based Labeling, but you need to separate the Japanese labels and English Labels into two fields. Rule-Based Labeling option enables you to add labels from different fields and customize them as you like by changing font name, color, size and use offset to place them above each other as you can see below:

[image]

To do this:

- Go to `Layer properties -> Labels`
- Select `Rule-Based Labeling`

[image]

- Define the fields that you want to use in the labeling, each one separately. In this example, I used Name_JP and Name_EN.
- Use the style for each one independently and customize each one as you like.
- The most important is to use `Offset` under `Placement` for the one of the labels so that they can be above each other. For the first label field I used the following placement settings:

[image]

For the second label field I used the following settings:

[image]

Tested on QGIS 3.0.1, But it can also applied in QGIS 2.18 because Rule-Based Labeling option is available.

Comment: Thank you for extensive answer @ahmadhanb. It is useful. Please, copy your message to the older question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48389/how-to-create-a-label-combining-different-font-sizes-or-types, I will rate it there.
The admin marked this post as a duplicate (so this post might be deleted). I implemented and maybe improved some steps. Especially I replaced Offset (which you do not have fully under control) by Data defined settings.

Comment: @jurajb Thanks for your advice. I copied my answer and paste it in the duplicate question, although, I don't see it duplicate.